# Recreate drawer actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I've implemented the drawer UI pattern following the official guide (http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) and it is working fine.

Now i want to replace the default actionbar with a "done-discard" actionbar upon the click of a button. This part is working fine. When the user clicks either "done" or "discard" i want to return to the drawer actionbar. I'm almost able to do that, except the navigation drawer icon at the top left, left of my app icon will not reappear.

This is what happens in my "discard" click event handler:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            inDragMode = false;
            com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar();

            actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE, ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);

            getSherlockActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself. Replace:

```
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE, ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
```

With:

```
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
```

I guess the "SetDisplyOptions" method got me confused.